# Why my Delete function deleting only First element in express with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, mongoose

when I press delete button of the particular element my delete function deleting only first element, y? 
**list.pug** (my view file)

```
ul
        each sport_list in sports_list
            li(class='form'):  a(href='/sport/'+sport_list.name) #{sport_list.name}

            form.form-horizontal(class='delete')
                input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf id='_csrf')
                input(type='hidden', name='id', value=sport_list.id id='id')
                .form-group
                    .col-sm-offset-3.col-sm-7
                        button.btn.btn-success(type='submit' class='form')
                            i.fa.fa-trash-o
                            | Delete

        else
            li There are no Sport
```

**main.js**(my main js lib file)

```
$(function() {
        $('.form').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '/deleteSport' + $("#id").val(),
                    data: {_csrf: $("#_csrf").val(), id: $("#id").val()}
                    // success: function(result) {
                    //     // Do something with the result
                    //     console.log('succesfully deleted'+result);
                    // }
                })
                    .done(function (json) {
                        console.log($("#id").val())
                        console.log(json);
                        $('.form').show();
                    });
            }); //missing ); here!
        });
    });
```

`sport.js`(my controller js)

```
exports.deleteSport = (req, res) => {

    Sport.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.body.id}, function(err, sport) {

        console.log(err,sport)
        if (err) {
            req.flash('errors', {msg: 'Something wrong'})
        }


        //res.redirect('/listsports');
        res.json({error:err,sport:sport});
    })
};
```

**app.js**(my app.js file)

```
app.post('/deleteSport:id', sportController.deleteSport);
```

can anyone here please tell me what is the mistake I had done?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to "deleting only first elemet" ( whatever that is supposed to mean ) but [`.findByIdAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) is being supplied with incorrect arguments. Should be `Sport.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id,function(err, sport) {`. That means both just the value rather an `Object` ( which would be `findOneAndRemove()` ) and `req.params.id` rather than `req.body.id`, because the `id` is in the URL and not the body.

Comment: @NeilLunn right now also it's deleting the only first element but clicked on second element

Comment: Aside from correcting the obvious mistake I was also pointing out that your "question" does not really present a reproducible case or demonstrate anything that people can "debug" themselves. You really need to do that when asking questions here. As far as "more obvious mistakes" there is `$("#id")` where things with `#` in a selector are "unique". Therefore you cannot possibly have multiple elements on a page identified by that, and if you do then only the "first" would be selected. Sounds like you need unique identifiers in your markup, or  click handler should be attached to specific element

Comment: but `$('.form').each(function()` for each element of object then why not selecting........?

Comment: You might be working within `.each()` but the value you are sending is `$("#id").val()`, which is only ever one single element on the entire page. You probably mean to name things `id="id_1"` and `id="id_2"` and so on and use an index from the elements marked as `.form` or something else. But you cannot use multiple things with `id="id"` in the markup and expect it to work.  That's why we have "className" in the first place. To apply to "multiple" things, and not just "one".

Comment: @NeilLunn **plz** can u elaborate how can I pass **className** with sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I resolve this issue myself
**list.pug** (my view file) just change **id=sport_list.id** and minor changes

```
 ul(class='listItem')
        each sport_list in sports_list
            li
                a(href='/sport/'+sport_list.name) #{sport_list.name}

                form.form-horizontal(class='delete')
                    input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf id='_csrf')
                    input(type='hidden', name='id', class="id" value=sport_list.id id=sport_list.id)
                    .form-group
                        .col-sm-offset-3.col-sm-7
                            button.btn.btn-success(type='submit' class='deletebutton')
                                i.fa.fa-trash-o
                                | Delete

            button.btn.btn-success(type='submit')
                i.fa.fa-trash-o
                | Delete

        else
            li There are no Sport
```

**main.js**(my main js lib file)instead of **.form** target on **form** Tag and getting **ID** `var id = $(form).find(".id").val()` code below with some minor changes

```
$(function() {
        $('form').each(function() {
            var form = this;
            $(form).find(".deletebutton").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();


                var id = $(form).find(".id").val()
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '/deleteSport/' + id,
                    data: {_csrf: $("#_csrf").val(), id: id}

                })
                    .done(function (json) {
                        console.log($("#id").val())
                        console.log(json);
                        $(form).closest('.listItem').remove();
            });
            });
        });
    });
```

**sport.js** use `findOneAndRemove` instead of `findByIdAndRemove`

```
exports.deleteSport = (req, res) => {

    Sport.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, sport) {

        console.log(err,sport)
        if (err) {
            req.flash('errors', {msg: 'Something wrong'})
        }


        //res.redirect('/listsports');
        res.json({error:err,sport:sport});
    })
};
```

Thats it!! :)